# Bootstrap V4 alpha - How to centrally align nav-items without touching css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

[image]

I have a nav bar at the left which has a few dropdowns. I want to make the text centrally align for the dropdowns or maybe a better representation of dropdowns in a nav bar. How to do that? (if possible without modifying css)

My current code snippet -

```
<nav class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 hidden-xs-down bg-faded sidebar">

          <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Region</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu">
                      <h6 class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</h6>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                  </div>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Category</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu">
                      <h6 class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</h6>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                  </div>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Brand</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu">
                      <h6 class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</h6>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                  </div>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Packaging</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu">
                      <h6 class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</h6>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                  </div>
              </li>

            <!--<li class="nav-item">-->
              <!--<a class="nav-link" href="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/#">Analytics</a>-->
            <!--</li>-->
          </ul>

        </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean "centrally align". You can just use text-center to horizontally align the text.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column text-center">
</ul>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/J8C7RwDIDW